# Cowin (api sethu) integration (unauthenticated access error)

Tags: php, api

I am trying to integrate cowin api with my application.. when I am using confirmOtp endpoint, I am getting forbidden error and unauthenticated access error. can anyone tell me how to generate the token..

Comment: Which API are you using? Public or Protected? Did you encrypt the OTP with SHA256 before posting it?

Comment: HI thanks for reply.. I am using api sethu website.. Now I am using protected api's.. Yes  I have encrypted the otp with sha256 before posting

Comment: https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin/cowin-protected-v2   this is the link of my api